# Retrieve data from a web page table using RSelenium

Tags: r, rselenium

I am trying to scrape the annual maximum flow data from this National River Flow Archive (UK) website:
http://nrfa.ceh.ac.uk/data/station/info/69032
using RSelenium.
I can't find a way to negotiate the drop down menu. At present I can semi-automate the process using:

```
library(RSelenium)
checkForServer()
startServer()
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", port = 4444, browserName = "firefox", platform = "LINUX")
remDr$open()
i <- "69032"
remDr$navigate(paste0("http://nrfa.ceh.ac.uk/data/station/peakflow/", i))
# read the raw html and parse
doc<-htmlParse(remDr$getPageSource()[[1]])
peak.flows <- as.numeric(readHTMLTable(doc)$tablesorter[, "Flow (m3/s)"])
```

This is a bit of a hack and involves me having to click a few buttons on the page rather than getting RSelenium to do it. Any suggestions as to how RSelenium can select the "Peak flow data" tab and then the "Maximum Annual (AMAX) data" option from the drop-down menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(RSelenium) 
checkForServer() 
startServer() 
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", port = 4444, browserName = "firefox", platform = "LINUX") 
remDr$open() i <- "69032"
remDr$navigate(paste0("http://nrfa.ceh.ac.uk/data/station/peakflow/", i))
remDr$findElement(using="css selector",'.selected a')$clickElement() 
Sys.sleep(5) 
remDr$findElement(using = "css selector", "#selectDataType")$clickElement()
remDr$findElement(using = "css selector", "#selectDataType")$sendKeysToElement(list(key="down_arrow", key="enter")) 
Sys.sleep(2)`
```

If you want to know about the css id of the element of interest, please install [SELECTOR GADGET] plugin into chrome. Highlight the element you want RSelenium to click, then grab the css id.